# How do I display hidden notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing a simple app that starts a service when a button is tapped... The service create an ongoing notification but I don't want it to display any icon in the status bar...

[image]

In this picture you can see WiFi ADB has a standard ongoing notification that cannot be dismissed...

Google Now (The 62 Cloudy), Automatic, and Automate do not display any icon when the notification bar is closed and they are in a separate group (under that grey line).

I looked everywhere for how to achieve that but can't find anything... Even the Android documentation which is usually quite exhaustive doesn't provide any information about it.

**EDIT:**

Right now this is how I display my notification:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Power Napp")
            .setContentText("Napping...")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: Did you try public NotificationCompat.Builder setOngoing (true)?

Comment: Remove set title, set content text and set small icon and re run the code, what happens then?

Comment: Nothing... Android provides a blank icon, standard title and standard text... but the notification is still where it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple trick. Add:

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
```

And the notification won't show the icon in the status bar.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN

isn't very clear about this but it's documented here:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority

Comment: Thank you very much... This is kinda poorly documented! Once I had an idea of what to look for I also find a better description of the behavior here http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority

Comment: Great, I added the link to the answer ;-)